# Vue: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_c' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, core-ui

I need to upgrade project from vue 2 to vue3
I am using coreui template. And in that I have upgrade vue, vuex, vue-router.
But when I serve the project it shows the following error in console.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_c' of undefined

[image]

There is no error in terminal. I have updated all router, vuex, vue with vue3 syntax.

Thanks for any help

Comment: It seems that CoreUI library doesn't support Vue3 yet https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-vue-admin-template/issues/238

Comment: @EugeneKarataev
As per doc they are supporting vue 3. https://prnt.sc/vplvd8. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it seems that CoreUI v3 is not currently compatible with Vue 3, because CoreUI v3 depends on Vue 2 (see dependencies tab): https://www.npmjs.com/package/@coreui/vue

Comment: @EugeneKarataev Thanks! Can you Please share admin template which support vue3. If you have any.

Comment: I have the same problem but I'm using BalmUI. I've seen this is compatible with vue3. Does anyone know why is this not working?

Comment: @BiancaBalan This might be because one of your dependency does not support vue3. Check dependency of each module.

Answer (score 2):

I have that problem also by using vue-qrcode-reader.

but I run `npm i vue3-qrcode-reader` instead of `npm i vue-qrcode-reader`, that fix my problem.

I guess maybe it doesn't support Vue3 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please import your Property and provide it at main.ts

Eg :

```
import { testProviderSymbol, createTestProviderState } from './store/modules/test/TestProvider';

createApp(App)

.provide(blogProviderSymbol, createBlogProviderState())

.mount('#app')
```